# How do you put grep commands into npm script?

Tags: grep, npm-scripts

I would like my start script to also include a grep command. In particular, I would like the `npm start` command to run `npm start |& grep -v error`

My `package.jcon`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
npm-run-script
```

Further details:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script